# Can "where" be used as a subordinate conjunction in place of "on which" when the location is logical rather than physica?

Tags: word-usage, where

This is in a technical document.  The sentence currently reads:

> With whole-object protection, all the data for each object in a replicated namespace is maintained on each HCP system in a replication topology, except on systems on which the namespace is on a metadata-only storage tier.

What you need to know:  A namespace exists ***on*** a system.  A namespace is a logical grouping of objects, not a physical thing.

The question:  Can "where" be used in place of "on which" in the sentence in question?

My opinion:  No.  But I"m not sure why.  All thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: My opinion: Yes.

Comment: There's a long history of "where" being used to indicate circumstance. It works fine in this sentence, too.

Comment: If you're not going to convert to _where_, which I agree with previous comments would be acceptable, you might consider the word for in place of the first on. To clarify :"_except for systems on which the namespace..._" etc. In fact you might consider that either way you go.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, absolutely; and "where" makes the sentence far less cumbersome and stilted. That is to say, clearer.

Also, consider changing the beginning "With" to "Using"